# How can I issue a command in i3 and then return to the same window?

Tags: i3

If I do this, it will focus Chromium and open up the print dialog,

```
i3-msg mark _last, "[class=Chromium] focus", exec xdotool key "Ctrl+P"
```

If I do this,

```
i3-msg mark _last, "[class=Chromium] focus", exec xdotool key "Ctrl+P" && sleep 0.5, "[con_mark=foo] _last"
```

Nothing happens. I'm just wanting to return to the window I marked. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus after the command is done,

```
i3-msg mark _last, '[class=Chromium] focus', exec "sh -c \"xdotool key Ctrl+P && i3-msg '[con_mark=_last] focus'\""
```